# App is not updating when I save changes to app.js NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I'm building my first NodeJs app, and I was hoping that the browser would update whenever I hit Control+S on my app.js file. For example, initially I have it outputting `Hello world`, then I do `node app.js`, visit http://localhost:3000 in my browser. If I go back to editing `app.js` and update it to be `Hello world2`, I have to cancel node via `Control+C`, then `node app.js` to see my updates. Not even doing `F5` in my browser will get the latest changes.

Comment: check nodemon https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: Your server has to be restarted to pick up new versions of the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to auto-restart your server when files are changed

Install:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Run:

```
nodemon ./server.js localhost 3000
```

Comment: But why does Node not do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was simply solved by switching to Chrome.
Apparently using Opera and http-server is not working as expected, since I receive changes to index.html instantly, but it takes around an hour to sync the changes made to app.js

Also found that even in Opera it works only if app.js is in the same folder as index. In my case I had projectFolder/src/app.js
so what I did was just moving app.js in the same projectFolder.
Somehow it fixed the problem for Opera even though using  should follow the path no matter if it has tons of folders or not.